# if/else statement on list that depends on query data

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a simple query and php echo statement that outputs an unordered list of results.

I want display an icon in front of the results where there's a certain value from the data.

This is what I have, but the first if statement is overlooked, presumably because of an inherent error in my code.

I believe the error resides in this line:  if (vopac >= 500 and llf >= 250).  The result of this is to spit out all of the else data.  The logic of that if statement is correct, but can I not use those values in PHP unless they are a declared variable?

```
$query = "SELECT b.cb_professionalname as name, b.cb_2013vopac as vopac, b.cb_2013llf as llf
from jos_comprofiler b, jos_users a
where a.id = b.user_id
and a.block=0
order by lastname";
$db->setQuery( $query ); 
$result = $db->loadObjectList(); 

echo "<ul  class='columns'>";
foreach($result as $row) 
  if (vopac >= 500 and llf >= 250)  {
    echo "<li><img src='images/icons/medal_gold_1.png' title='Gold Status'>$row->name</li>";
  } else { 
    echo "<li>$row->name</li>";
  }
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: What type of data is vopac and llf?  What if you put the values in quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would need to use `$row->vopac` and `$row->llf`

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, The reason you would need to use the above is because each row is being returned as an object, and therefore you would access each objects memebers using the arrow (->) operator

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($result as $row)  {
if ($row["vopac"] >= 500 and $row["llf"] >= 250)  {
echo "<li><img src='images/icons/medal_gold_1.png' title='Gold Status'>$row->name</li>";
} else { 
echo "<li>$row->name</li>";
}
}
```

if that does't work try type casting

```
if ((int)$row["vopac"] >= 500 AND (int)$row["llf"] >= 250){
```